# Wrong numbering

Tags: numbering

I'm using Book class. Document structure uses chapters, sections, subsections, examples, exercises. I'm getting a wrong numbering; for example in my pdf document I can have this reference «Refer to exercice 3.5» while exercice 3.5 refer in reality to another one. Thank you for your help.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=16cm, paperheight=24cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedLeft}X}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}

\input{structure.cls} % Insert the commands.tex file which contains the majority of the structure behind the template

\begin{document}

\subsection{My section}\label{section:Introduction}

    \lipsum[1][1]

    \begin{example}
            \lipsum[2][1]
    \end{example}\label{example:demonstration1}

    \begin{example}
            \lipsum[3][1]
    \end{example}\label{example:demonstration2}

    \begin{example}
            \lipsum[4][1]
    \end{example}\label{example:demonstration3}

    \begin{exercise}
            \lipsum[3][1]
    \end{exercise}\label{exercise:DoYourSelf1}

    \begin{exercise}
            \lipsum[4][1]
    \end{exercise}\label{exercise:DoYourSelf2}

    \begin{exercise}
            \lipsum[5][1]
    \end{exercise}\label{exercise:DoYourSelf3}


Section~\ref{section:Introduction}

Exercise~\ref{exercise:DoYourSelf1}

Example~\ref{example:demonstration1}

Exercise refer example~\ref{example:demonstration2}

Exercise

Careful do exercise~\ref{exercise:DoYourSelf2} first.
\end{document}
```

Comment: your `label` are not in any environment or following a caption or section heading, so they all reference the same subsection.

Comment: using ` .cls` extension for a file that is `\input` seems very confusing although not technically an error, but as you have not provided that file we can no run your example.

Comment: Are we just supposed to guess how the `exercise` and `example` environments are defined? Most likely the problem can be solved by David's suggestion of moving the labels inside the environments rather than after them, but even that might not work depending on how they're defined, which we can't tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding *labels* to reference environments (figures, tables, equations, *etc*), you must put the `\label`:

- inside the environment

  - after the caption, if present.

that means either

```
\begin{equation}\label{eqn1} 
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
```

or

```
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2\label{eqn1} 
\end{equation}
```

or

```
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\label{eqn1} \end{equation}
```

or

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example.pdf}
\caption{Dummy caption}\label{dummyfigure}
\end{figure}
```